# Condtional Statement to select CSS in dotnentnuke

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to implement media queries in the dotnetnuke framework.
Is there a way to conditional select what css to use? Im trying to stop IE6/7/8 which don't have media query support to not access the  media query CSS:

heres and extract from my code which doesn't work:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ddn" TagName="MENU" src="~/DesktopModules/DDRMenu/Menu.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ddn" TagName="MOBMENU" src="~/DesktopModules/DDRMenu/Menu.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement" Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web.Client" %>

<![if !(IE 6)|(IE 7)|(IE 8)]>
    <dnn:DnnCssInclude runat="server" FilePath="mq.css" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />                    
<![endif]>


        <div id="wrapper">


            <div id="header">
                <div id="logo">
                    <dnn:LOGO runat="server" id="dnnLOGO" />
                </div>
```

Comment: Thought i had cracked it but no tried this: <dnn:DnnCssInclude runat="server" FilePath="mq.css" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" Condition="!(IE 6)|(IE 7)|(IE 8)"/> but it just removes my skin altogether and uses a default one?!??!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this skin object to realize conditional loading of CSS:

[40fingers style helper skin object](http://www.40fingers.net/WeblogsNews/Weblogs/tabid/58/ID/102/language/nl-NL/DotNetNuke-Style-Helper-Skin-Object-020500-Released.aspx)

Comment: I trying to use this but it doesn't seem to work <fortyfingers:STYLEHELPER ID="STYLEHELPER1" Browser = "!IE" AddCssFile="mq.css" runat="server" /> it includes the mq.css for all browsers including IE?!?

Comment: Ah typo on my part should be ifbrowser <fortyfingers:STYLEHELPER ID="STYLEHELPER1" IfBrowser = "!IE<9" AddCssFile="mq.css" runat="server" />

Answer (score 0):

DnnCssInclude doesn't have the 'Condition' attribute, you have to use this skin object instead:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="STYLES" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Styles.ascx" %>
<dnn:STYLES runat="server" ID="StylesIE7" Name="IE7Minus" StyleSheet="ie7skin.css" Condition="LT IE 8" UseSkinPath="true"/>
```

The code above is taken from the DarkKnight skin that comes with DNN6.

Do you really need to hide media queries from older browsers? Browsers that don't support media queries will just ignore them.

Edit:
What's the syntax of your media queries? If you use

```
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {.box  { background-color: red; }}
```

then IE6,7 will ignore it, I've just tested it.
If you use something like this:

```
@media screen {.box  { background-color: red; }}
```

or

```
@media screen, all and (min-width: 300px) {.box  { background-color: red; }}
```

Then IE6,7 will pick up those styles. You may need to tweak your syntax. Read [this article](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/safe-media-queries/), it's old but still applies to IE6,7.

Comment: Browsers that don't support media queries(IE6/7/8) use the media query CSS styles and this overwrites the main CSS ...